# Delete appointments after a date

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar

I have a daily meeting in my calendar that I'm not going to anymore (because my work for that project is over).  I'd like to remove the occurrences after today but leave the ones in the past.

I've seen how I can accomplish this if I'm the meeting organizer, but I'm not.

How can I delete all future occurrences?

Here's a screenshot of what happens when I try to delete.  It clearly states that *all* occurrences will be deleted.

[image: transcription below]

> Do you want to delete all occurrences of the recurring appointment "Hawkins: Daily 2016 Stand-ups", or just this one?
>
> - Delete this occurrence.
> - Delete the series.
>
> [OK] [Cancel]

Comment: @BramMooij, the question is tagged with Outlook.  If I delete the event, it removes all past ones, too.

Comment: My bad, I sometimes forget about the tags. Thanks for the update. I think this link might provide you with the answer: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Cancel-all-future-meetings-in-a-series-9eaeee8c-bfe3-46a0-a092-9a2707f3b133 . Or is the problem that you cannot do this because it's not your event?

Comment: @BramMooij no worries.